# How do I find SPAN tag containing DIV tag with notepad++ regex for W3C Validation?

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to fix my HTML views for W3C validation. On error is that I had some rare div or structural tags in a span tag. Here's a fake example made from my  HTML codes :

```
<div style="margin-left:10px;">
<h2>Sub Title</h2>
<span><span class="bold_text">Phones : </span> 000-000-000000 / 000-000-000000 </span>
<br/>
<span><span class="bold_text">Email : </span>
    <ul>
        <li>For Support use <a href="mailto:support@email.com" >support@email.com</a></li>
        <li>For CopyRights use <a href="mailto:copyright@email.com" >copyright@email.com</a></li> 
        <li>For Technical issue use <a href="mailto:staff@email.com" >staff@email.com</a></li> 
    </ul>
</span>

<span>
    <span class="bold_text">Location : </span>
    <div class="address_container">#0, City, Region, Country</div>
</span>

<div class="map_container" style="margin-top:10px;display:inline-block;width:90%;height:400px;" >
    @yield('map_member')
</div>
```

I'm playing with regex101 and so far I got this :

```
<span[^>]*>[.\s\S]*<div[\s\S]*<\/div>[\s\S]*<\/span>  /gm
```

It must match new lines and spaces. But this select the 1st  and finishes on the last span ending tag . But I want it to point only to :

```
<span>
    <span class="bold_text">Location : </span>
    <div class="address_container">#0, City, Region, Country</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace those DIV within the SPAN, while there is SPAN within the SPAN?

One can also assume that if it ended with SPAN that it also started with SPAN.

So this regex just uses a positive lookahead to check if the DIV is followed by 0 or more enclosed DIV or SPAN, then closed with SPAN.

```
\s*<div[^<>]*>[^<>]*</div>(?=(?:\s*<(div|span)[^<>]*>[^<>]*</\1>)*[^<>]*</span>)
```

Replace with nothing and it'll be spick-and-span.

Comment: That resolves perfectly my problem of finding those div. It points to the div tag directly, so it's better than what I was expecting! BIG THANKS to you!

Comment: I did not had div on them, so I replace div with any word character \w{1,4} to match any tag

    \s*<\w{1,4}[^<>]*>[^<>]*<\/\w{1,4}>(?=(?:\s*<(\w{1,4}|span)[^<>]*>[^<>]*<\/\1>)*[^<>]*<\/span>)

And I realized I had a bunch of headings tag inside of my span tags, which W3C does not validate.